# Make a bootstrap affix draggable around the screen

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap affix which is like a sticky window. This shows some meta data about the information the user is hovering on right now. I am trying to make this sticky notification movable around the screen so that the user can move it out of his way if it obstructs what he is seeing. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution; I have inserted a button inside the affix to set on it jQuery UI draggable; the same is used to toggle the affix back.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav" class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="span12"> <a class="brand" href="#">My Brand</a>
 <span class="navbar-text">
                    This is my navbar.
                    </span>

                    <button id="mover" class="btn-danger pull-right">Move me!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- container -->
        </div>
        <!-- navbar-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- navbar -->
</div>
```

Code:

```
$('#nav').affix();
$("#nav").data("left", $("#nav").position().left).data("top", $("#nav").position().top);

$('#mover').click(function () {
    if ($('#nav').hasClass("movable")) {
        $('#nav').draggable('destroy');
        $("#nav").animate({
            "left": $("#nav").data("left"),
                "top": $("#nav").data("top")
        });
        $(window).scrollTop();
$("#nav").removeAttr("style")
        $('#nav').removeClass("movable");
        $(this).text("Move me!")
    } else {
        $('#nav').draggable({cursor: "crosshair"});
        $('#nav').addClass("movable");
        $(this).text("Affix me!")
    }
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/YA2kX/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought JqueryUI and bootstrap were not supposed to be used together.

Comment: However I wanted the affix to stay an affix all the time but it should be draggable to another location of user's choice if its coming in the way.